# Securing REST WebApi2 service with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

I am currently developing a WebApi 2 service which is hosted in Azure.  I now need to add Authentication and ideally Authorization to this service.  I was expecting to be able to do this with Azure Active Directory but have a number of questions

1. Will my users have to login via the standard Azure sign in portal?
2. Will my users be forced to use specific email domains (ie microsoft) when creating an account?
3. Will I be able to programatically add a user into the directory along with Authorization info (aka rights management)?
4. Will I programatically be able to modify a users details such as forgotton password etc

Sorry for the general question, but I am stuck trying to find out if I am looking at the right technology to be able to meet these requirements.  If not, would really appreciate any suggestions on what to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will my users have to login via the standard Azure sign in portal?

Yes, but the branding of the portal can be changed in the [basic and premium](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) editions of Azure AD.

> Will my users be forced to use specific email domains (ie microsoft) when creating an account?

No, you can register your own domain and associate it with a directory. Or you can sync on-premise accounts to an Azure AD directory and use those email addresses.

> Will I be able to programatically add a user into the directory along with Authorization info (aka rights management)?

Yes, using the [Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) you can create and manage users. You can also assign them roles or make them part of a security group.

> Will I programatically be able to modify a users details such as forgotton password etc

Yes, using the Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for this - from what I have read, the graph  api is readonly - i will give it a try

Comment: @MarkRuse No, the Graph api can be used to change data in the directory also. Just make sure you have the correct permissions. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#createuser

Comment: Thanks for this - Final clarity question - for user accounts, can the be just username and / or there own existing email address or do they need to be accounts created against my domain?

Comment: You can create new user accounts in your directory or add existing accounts to your directory. See here for more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users/. Obviously, if you're syncing on-premise accounts to Azure AD using Azure AD Connect, you need to create those accounts in on-premise AD.